# Using Nginx as load balancer and random requests hang for a while, then throughput really slow

Tags: nginx

I currently have an Nginx configuration below. It works fine most of the time. For some reason there are a certain percentage of requests that take really long, they don't drop. Maybe up to say a few minutes.

Then they come through, sending the file at 5-10kbs per second versus a normal request might go upwards of a few megs per second and start within a few seconds.

Any help on debugging this would be appreciated.

```
user sysadminguy;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 25000;
events {
        worker_connections 1080;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        access_log off;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        #limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:100m rate=10r/m;
        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
        upstream backend {
            least_conn;
            server 1.1.1.2:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=1;
            server 1.1.1.3:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=1;
            server 1.1.1.4:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=1;
            server 1.1.1.5:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=1;
            server 1.1.1.6:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=2;
            server 1.1.1.7:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=2;

       }
        server {
            listen      80;
            server_name server1.example.com;
            location / {
                return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
            }
        }
        server {
            listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
            server_name server1.example.com;
            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server1.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server1.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

            location = / {
                 return 301 https://example.com;
            }


            location / {
                #limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_read_timeout 3600;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_pass http://backend;

             }

            location /nginx_status {
                 # Turn on stats
                 stub_status on;
                 access_log   off;
                 # only allow access from 192.168.1.5 #
                 #allow 192.168.1.5;
                 #deny all;
             }
        }
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try disabling the `keepalive_timeout` value by setting it to `0`.

The big thing that sticks out to me in your config is this line:

```
keepalive_timeout 65;
```

According to the official Nginx docs, the default value for [`keepalive_timeout`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout) is 65 seconds. But based on my experience, the keep alive setting for any web server — Nginx, Apache and even IIS — should be around 2 to 3 seconds.

Knowing that I would set that value to `0` to effectively disable the keep alive stuff in Nginx like this:

```
keepalive_timeout 0;
```

Then restart Nginx and see if that clears things up.

The best way to understand keep alive settings is that the keep alive is only of value on servers where one connection to Nginx is going to deliver a ton of associated assets to a client browser at a time.

So imagine something like a photo gallery page filled with dozens of images. Setting a high keep alive setting *might* help cleanly and efficiently deliver all of those images all at once via one Nginx connection.

That is the theory. In practice, keep alive settings are best disabled or simply set to a low enough value to be practical. Knowing that you *might* want to try setting that value to something like 2 seconds like this:

```
keepalive_timeout 2;
```

Restart Nginx and see how that works out. Should honestly be as performant as setting that value to `0`.

#### That said, *maybe* the `fail_timeout` values for the `upstream` config have something to do with the issue as well.

But taking a deeper look at your config and I see this chunk of settings:

```
upstream backend {
    least_conn;
    server 1.1.1.2:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=1;
    server 1.1.1.3:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=1;
    server 1.1.1.4:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=1;
    server 1.1.1.5:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=1;
    server 1.1.1.6:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=2;
    server 1.1.1.7:3292 fail_timeout=10s weight=2;
}
```

Based on my own experience, that `fail_timeout` setting should not be `10s` but instead be `0` so the config is:

```
upstream backend {
    least_conn;
    server 1.1.1.2:3292 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
    server 1.1.1.3:3292 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
    server 1.1.1.4:3292 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
    server 1.1.1.5:3292 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
    server 1.1.1.6:3292 fail_timeout=0 weight=2;
    server 1.1.1.7:3292 fail_timeout=0 weight=2;
}
```

Restart Nginx and see how that works. Based on your description, it seems to be each node in that backend pool would wait 10 seconds before failing. So, if for example, there were some overall network connection issue, the nodes in that pool might not ever be reachable until 60 seconds later (6 times 10 second delay per node).

If for some reason that ends up giving you something like a 503 (Service Unavailable) error, then maybe setting a real value for `fail_timeout` has value. Maybe set it to 3s and see how that works?

In general I think the `keepalive_timeout` setting is the core issue here. The `fail_timeout` *might* play a factor, but I don’t know enough about the deeper setup to make a call on that.

Comment: Can reload be used instead of restart?

Comment: @nadermx Sure. Try it out. The way I understand it only certain config values change when `reload` is used versus `restart` (which is effectively just `stop` and `start` combined)/

Comment: so it seems, it's happening again now, but not on the first request, but the 2nd.

Comment: @nadermx I don’t know what to tell you. I would look into making the `upstream backend` tweaks I recommend in my answer. I would also investigate why some are `weight=1` and others are `weight=2`. This could all be an issue of the network connections to those upstream backend servers are genuinely flaky. No easy way to debug. Best of luck.